# can't find logs while copying files in usb

Tags: usb, logging

Where can I find logs for copying files from local to USB? I'm using GUI to copy files.

OS:Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Copying files from disk to USB is nowhere logged.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are referring to the journal of some file systems, no general logs (of which I am aware) are made when files are copied to a USB drive.  The most common file systems used on USB drives (FAT32, exFAT) do not contain such journals.

I know of no general utility to view or work with file system journals.  However, you *might* find the following information useful:

- For NTFS, you *might* be able to use `ntfsinfo`.  You can read more about the NTFS Journal:

  - [Digital Forensics – NTFS Change Journal](https://countuponsecurity.com/2017/05/25/digital-forensics-ntfs-change-journal/)
  - [GitHub: ExtractUsnJrnl](https://github.com/jschicht/ExtractUsnJrnl)
- You *might* be able to use `xfs_db` for xfs.
- For ext3/4, you can use `debugfs` to dump the journal and [ext4magic](http://ext4magic.sourceforge.net/ext4magic_en.html) to search and recover files.